# LastPass buggy with IE 11

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, password-management, lastpass

We've been using LastPass as our password manager for the last couple years on our office computer running `IE 11` on Windows 7. It kinda worked, but was very buggy and was hard to use for a general (non-techy) users.

Then yesterday after installing a batch of recent Windows updates when I click the Last Pass Vault link it would open this page and hang up indefinitely:

[image]

I tried reinstalling the plug-in ... Contacted their support ... That didn't help.

So any idea how to fix this?

PS. We have to use `IE 11` because of the group policy restrictions on that computer. Firefox or Chrome do not seem to work with GPOs.

Comment: This appears more of a security policy than a problem with the Lastpass IE extension.  There are tons of alternatives to LastPass.  You should use one of those.  I loaded up my Windows 7 SP1 VM, installed all pending updates through today, and the LastPass IE11 extension work flawlessly.

Comment: @Ramhound: Well, is there a log file that I can review to see why it's not loading? Why do I have to do it for them (LastPass) in the first place. It's their buggy software. They need to anticipate all this stuff and not the end-users. It's been working fine until about yesterday. And the only change was the Windows updates. (I swear that LogMeIn can ruin pretty much any good product once they acquire it.)

Comment: Changes to your machine's security posture aren't the fault of Lastpass.  This is typically caused by security measures connected to JavaScript, since Lastpass uses JavaScript, for pretty much everything.  Your network administrator can help diagnose what recent changes were made could be at fault.

Comment: @Ramhound: I am the IT dept. It's a small company. As for your other claim, just like I said in a previous message, **nothing** was changed in the security policies on that system. The only change is the Windows update.

Comment: "And the only change was the Windows updates." - isn't enough detail to conclude anything.  You don't even specify which updates you installed.  I will come back to this question, once you remove both rant about Lastpass, and your service recommendation.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a fix or not, but I got it resolved by uninstalling LastPass and going with Dashlane. A little bit more expense but **so much more user friendly password manager**. I'll be switching all my systems now on.